# How do I get the number of subunits from a PDB file with awk , python or biopython?

Tags: python, awk, bioinformatics, biopython

I have PDB(text) files which are in a directory. I would like to print the number of subunits from each PDB file.

1. Read all lines in a pdb file that start with `ATOM`
2. The fifth column of the `ATOM` line contains `A`, `B`, `C`, `D` etc.
3. If it contains only `A` the number of subunit is 1. If it contains `A` and `B`, the number of subunits are 2.  If it contains `A`, `B`, and `C` the number of subunits are 3.

1kg2.pdb file

```
ATOM   1363  N   ASN A 258      82.149 -23.468   9.733  1.00 57.80           N  
ATOM   1364  CA  ASN A 258      82.494 -22.084   9.356  1.00 62.98           C  
ATOM   1395  C   MET B 196      34.816 -51.911  11.750  1.00 49.79           C  
ATOM   1396  O   MET B 196      35.611 -52.439  10.963  1.00 47.65           O
```

1uz3.pdb file

```
ATOM   1384  O   ARG A 260      80.505 -20.450  15.420  1.00 22.10           O 
ATOM   1385  CB  ARG A 260      78.980 -18.077  15.207  1.00 36.88           C 
ATOM   1399  SD  MET B 196      34.003 -52.544  16.664  1.00 57.16           S 
ATOM   1401  N   ASP C 197      34.781 -50.611  12.007  1.00 44.30           N
```

2b69.pdb file

```
ATOM   1393  N   MET B 196      33.300 -54.017  12.033  1.00 46.46           N  
ATOM   1394  CA  MET B 196      33.782 -52.714  12.566  1.00 49.99           C
```

desired output

```
pdb_id   subunits

 1kg2      2
 1uz3      3
 2b69      1
```

How can I do this with awk, python or Biopython?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What have you tried? Have you taken a look at the `Bio.PDB.PDBParser` class in BioPython? There's documentation [here](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/tutorial/Tutorial.html#htoc138) and even a [paper about it](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/14630660)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an [array](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Arrays.html#Arrays) to record all seen values for the fifth column.

```
$ gawk '/^ATOM/ {seen[$5] = 1} END {print length(seen)}' 1kg2.pdb
2
```

**Edit:** Using gawk 4.x you can use [`ENDFILE`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/BEGINFILE_002fENDFILE.html#BEGINFILE_002fENDFILE) to generate the required output:

```
BEGIN {
  print "pdb_id\t\tsubunits"
  print
}

/^ATOM/ {
  seen[$5] = 1
}

ENDFILE {
  print FILENAME, "\t", length(seen)
  delete seen
}
```

The result:

```
$ gawk -f pdb.awk 1kg2.pdb 1uz3.pdb 2b69.pdb
pdb_id          subunits

1kg2.pdb         2
1uz3.pdb         3
2b69.pdb         1
```

Comment: The redirection isn't necessary.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. code works only for single .I tried the following code for multiple files.gawk '/^ATOM/ {seen[$5] = 1} END {print length(seen)}' file/*.pdb.But it didn't work. How to change the code for multiple files? I also need to print the name of files with the subunits.

Comment: Try the next answer.  But do a little thinking first - if you need to print the name of a file, then have you tried using a "print" statement with a "filename" (either in a shell loop around the gawk command, or in a python script)?

Comment: @user1672711 I've edited my answer to produce the output you want with gawk 4.x.

Answer (score 0):

A [dictionary](http://docs.python.org/py3k/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) is one way to count unique occurrences. The following assigns a meaningless value (0) to each subunit, since all you care about is the number of unique subunits (dictionary keys).

```
import os

for fn in os.listdir():
    if ".pdb" in fn:
        sub = {}
        with open(fn, 'r') as f:
            for line in f:
                c = line.split()
                if len(c) > 5 and c[0] == "ATOM":
                    sub[c[4]] = 0
        print(fn, len(sub.keys()))
```

(A brand new user deserves an answer along with a pointer to http://whathaveyoutried.com/.  Subsequent questions should include evidence that the user has actually tried to solve the problem.)